# Generate Images using php

Tags: php

How i can generate the below image using php

[image: Image Original Source]

I used the below php code to generate the image

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = imagecreate(300, 300);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 21, 125, 126);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

$blue = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

ImageFilledEllipse($im, 50, 120, 75, 75, $white);
ImageFilledEllipse($im, 250, 100, 75, 75, $white);



imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But i dint get the original image smoothness

**PHP Generated Image**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply filter to your image using [`imagefilter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) with the `IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH` argument.

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH,100);
```

Comment: @S.Varun, Sorry forgot to add the smoothing level.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, it would be good to say why, i.e. syntax error, its working but not doing what you expect? its causing a server error? what do you mean?

Comment: @Jon Taylor i mean that there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

`imagecreate` creates a palette-based image, which does not include anti-aliasing (in particular because you haven't allocated the "in-between" colours). Try `imagecreatetruecolor` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an image of a particular size then no matter how you do it, when you zoom into such an image you are always going to get unsmooth edges.

The problem is you are zooming in on the browser after the PHP image has been rendered.  Why not use a vector based library in javascript to draw your images, that way when you zoom in the vector graphic is redrawn for the appropriate scale.  Eliminating your jagged edges.

Comment: i am not zooming the browser